# How do associative arrays work?

Tags: awk

```
bash-3.00# cat iplogs.txt
180607 093423   123.12.23.122  133
180607 121234   125.25.45.221  153
190607 084849   202.178.23.4   44
190607 084859   164.78.22.64   12
200607 012312   202.188.3.2    13
210607 084849   202.178.23.4   34
210607 121435   202.178.23.4   32
210607 132423   202.188.3.2    167

bash-3.00# awk '{ip[$3]++;} END{for (var in ip)\
print var, "access", ip[var]," times"}' iplogs.txt
202.188.3.2 access 2  times
164.78.22.64 access 1  times
202.178.23.4 access 3  times
125.25.45.221 access 1  times
123.12.23.122 access 1  time
```

The above output is unclear to me. How is `$3` is incremented for every repeated
value?

I expected that values assigned to array `ip` would be like:

```
ip[123.12.23.122]=0
ip[125.25.45.221]=1
```

and so on.

So I tried this, but the value of array `ip[var]` did not get printed.

```
bash-3.00# awk '{ip[$3]++;} END{for (var=0;var <= NR; var++)\
print var, ip[var]}' iplogs.txt
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associative arrays use strings as keys, not integer indices.*  The key in this case is `$3`, which is an `awk` field variable corresponding to the third (3rd) field.  In your sample input, this would be the 3rd column which contains strings that look like IPv4 addresses.  In the expression `ip[$3]++`, if `$3` is `"202.188.3.2"`, then `ip["202.188.3.2"]` gets incremented.  Since `$3` is `"202.188.3.2"` a total of two times in your sample input, `ip["202.188.3.2"]` gets incremented two times.  Since it started at `0` at the beginning as all uninitialized awk variables do, it ends up with a value of `2`.

Your first example uses `for (var in ip)`.  This is the correct way to iterate over an array with unknown keys.  Your second example uses `for (var = 0; var <= NR; var++)`.  However, as I said above, `ip` was created as an associative array whose keys are *strings that look like IPv4 addresses*, **not** integer indices.  The elements `ip[0]`, `ip[1]`, ... do not exist because they were never assigned to (because at no point was `$3` ever `0`, `1`, `2` ... ), which is why you get empty output (`""`).

---

<sup>* In `awk`, integer array indices are actually first converted to strings, so `a[1]` and `a["1"]` are the same element.</sup>

Comment: thanks @jw013 i got that but i am assuming ip[$3] gets incremented for each line that means value of ip[202.188.3.2] should be 8. but how it gets counted to 2.

Comment: is it incrementing for every repeated value? `202.188.3.2 access 2  times`

Comment: @munish  The value of `$3` is not the same for every line, so `ip[$3]` is not the same for every line, so the same element is not being incremented for every line.